# UIpagecontrol in android

Tags: android, iphone

can anyone tell me that how can i use UIpagecontrol control of iphone by using it we can scroll horizontally any page.like this

http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/01/multiple-virtual-pages-in-uiscrollview.html

Comment: You want to use `UIPageControl` in an Android app? Yeh, that's kind of not going to work... Or do you want to know what the equivalent is on Android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find [here](https://github.com/pakerfeldt/android-viewflow) good examples of `UIPageControl`

you can use it as you use a normal `View` widgets.

Comment: i like this example screen srt and i thought of them it is exactly what i want but i am trouble in use this project from git hub so can you guide me on this? +1

Comment: You can download the code as zip. look for `Zip` button near top of page.

Comment: i have download it and try it but some layout file and some java file is confuse me

Comment: there is `viewflow-example` and `viewflow` are exist so can you tell me which one is use

Comment: `viewflow-example` will show you how to use the `viewflow`. actually you will need to reference the `viewflow` in your original project.