# Name of this iOS UI element and its Android alternative?

Tags: android, ios

This iOS element is often met in iOS apps.

[image]

Like a horizontal scrollview with dots representing which page is currently active.

What is its iOS name? I thought it was `uiscrollview`, but viewing its images, I saw that they don't look the same.

The second part, what is its best Android alternative? I am looking for its port on Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the first part of your question is that the iOS control is known as a [UIPageController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

As for the second part, [here's some open source code](https://github.com/pakerfeldt/android-viewflow) that you might be able to incorporate into your Android project, which I found in this [closely related (or possibly duplicate?) question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9583576/uipagecontrol-in-android).

Comment: This can be duplicate indeed. Thanks for a reply thou.

Comment: A more conventional replacement in Android would be a `ViewPager`, using one of the ViewPagerIndicator library's indicators (e.g., `CirclePageIndicator`).